# Process files in chunks based on their numbered names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

In one folder, I have hundreds of files named:

```
miserables-0001.png
miserables-0002.png
miserables-0003.png
...
miserables-0010.png
miserables-0011.png
...
miserables-0100.png
miserables-0101.png
...
miserables-0999.png
miserables-1000.png
...
```

What I want is to use the imagemagick -append command to append every twenty files in one png vertically.
So, the first 20 files

```
miserables-0001.png miserables-0002.png ... miserables-0020.png
```

will be appended in

```
miserables-appended-0001.png
```

and the second 20 files

```
miserables-0021.png miserables-0022.png ... miserables-0040.png
```

will be appended in

```
miserables-appended-0002.png
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can accomplish this:

**Read from file**

Put your file names in a text file. Suppose you've a `file.txt` that has input names such as:

> miserables-0001.png
>
> miserables-0002.png
>
> miserables-0003.png
>
> ...
>
> miserables-0020.png

then you can apply `convert` by:

```
convert @file.txt result.gif
```

**Input Range**

You can supply a range of inputs to `convert` based on their numbering. For your inputs, you can do:

```
convert miserables-000%d.png[1-9] result.gif
```

Read [ImageMagick documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) for further details.

Comment: One issues with the latter solution, is that it would read hundreds of files into memory and he may not have enough memory.  The first approach is fine. But a better solution would be to write script loops to read in only 20 images at a time. That depends upon the OS (Windows or Unix), which has not been specified. Also -append has been left out in both commands here and needs to be placed before the output image

Comment: The question tags declare that I use Windows.

Comment: @fmw42 Obviously he'd need script loops, he mentions in the question that he wants to read 20 images at a time. So either he writes a loop or unrealistically, he does it manually. My examples are meant to show `convert` file input style, I assumed he knew the proper commands to append images.

Answer (score 0):

The `%d`  approach doesn't work because it ignores the leading zeros and you would have to compensate that for each range 1-9 10-99 100-999 1000-9999 what makes it difficult to catch chunks of 20.

So it's the file approach with two stacked counting `for /l` loops.
To get leading zeroes it's easiest to prepend the number with a 1 and use the last 4 digits with substrings.

To check results the batch creates the files with the scheme
`miserables-#xxxx-yyyy.ext`

```
@Echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Prefix=miserables"
:: Get Max png count
:: (prepend with 1 to avoid set /A interpreting leading 0 as octal)
for /f "tokens=2 delims=-." %%A in ('Dir /B %Prefix%-*.png') Do @set "Max=1%%A"
Echo Max = %Max:~1%

:: loop from 0001 step 20 to %Max%
For /l %%A in (10001,20,%Max%) Do (
    Set From=%%A
    Set /A To=%%A+19
    If !To! gtr %Max% Set To=%Max%
    Set "File=%Prefix%-#!From:~-4!-!To:~-4!"
    Echo Processing !File!
    Del "!File!.txt" >NUL 2>&1
    For /l %%B in (!From!,1,!To!) Do (
        Set _B_=%%B
        >> "!File!.txt" Echo %Prefix%-!_B_:~-4!.png
    )
    Call Magick @!File!.txt -append !File!.png
)
```

I used generated number pictures for testing:

[image]

Whoever is interested in how:

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\09\02\GenPNGs.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /l %%A in (10001,1,10205) Do (
    Set "#=%%A"&Set "#=!#:~1!"
    magick convert ^
        -size 200x85 canvas:none -background white^
        -font Courier-New -pointsize 72 ^
        -draw "text 15,60 '!#!'" -channel RGBA -gaussian 0x6 ^
        -fill black -stroke blue ^
        -draw "text 10,55 '!#!'" ^
        miserables-!#!.png
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your comfortable with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I would recommend leveraging the [seq](/questions/tagged/seq) or other standard utilities.

I can think of two approaches, but I'm sure other folks can come up with simplified one-liners.

#### Nested loop

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PREFIX="miserables-"
SUFFIX=".png"

# Get count of files
TOTAL=$(ls -l ${PREFIX}*${SUFFIX} | wc -l | bc)

# Create output cursor to increment with each 20th iteration.
CURSOR=0

# Iterate start of each 20
for START in $(seq 1 20 $TOTAL)
do
    END=$(($START + 19))
    FILES=""
    # Collect each filename
    for ITER in $(seq -f "%04g" $START $END)
    do
        # Build filename
        FILE="${PREFIX}${ITER}${SUFFIX}"
        # Double check that the file exists.
        if [ -f $FILE ]; then
            FILES="${FILES} ${FILE}"
        fi
    done
    # Increment the output cursor
    CURSOR=$(($CURSOR + 1))
    # Write output file
    convert $FILES -append output/miserables-appended-${CURSOR}.png
done
```

### Only act on the 20<sup>th</sup> item

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PREFIX="miserables-"
SUFFIX=".png"
CURSOR=0;
OUTPUT_CURSOR=0;
FILES=""

# Find all files
for FILE in $(ls ${PREFIX}*${SUFFIX})
do
    # Increment cursor
    CURSOR=$(($CURSOR + 1))
    # Append file to list
    FILES="${FILES} $FILE"
    # If we're on the twentieth file, create output
    if [[ $(($CURSOR % 20)) -eq 0 ]]; then
        # Incement output cursor
        OUTPUT_CURSOR=$(($OUTPUT_CURSOR + 1))
        # Write output file
        convert $FILES -append output/miserables-appended-${OUTPUT_CURSOR}.png
        # Reset file list
        FILES=""
    fi
done
```